# NODE JS - problem looping through POST request featuring an if/else statement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm building a small server for an auction app with 3 hard coded users.
To match the username and password with the hard coded users details when they sign in, I'm using a for loop inside my POST request. It only works for the first user, so it seems my loop might not iterate through the other two users.

Here is my hard coded database:

```
const database = {
    users: [
        {
            username: 'User1',
            password: 'IamUserOne',
            itemOneBid: 0,
            itemTwoBid: 0,
            itemThreeBid: 0,
            itemFourBid: 0,
            itemFiveBid: 0,
            itemSixBid: 0,
        },
        {
            username: 'User2',
            password: 'IamUserTwo',
            itemOneBid: 0,
            itemTwoBid: 0,
            itemThreeBid: 0,
            itemFourBid: 0,
            itemFiveBid: 0,
            itemSixBid: 0,
        },
        {
            username: 'Admin',
            password: 'IamTheBoss'
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my Post request:

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    for (var i=0; i < database.users.length; i++) {
            if (req.body.username === database.users[i].username && 
                req.body.password === database.users[i].password) {
            res.json('successful signin');
        } else {
        res.status(400).json('error logging in');
        }
    }
})
```

It works fine if I sign in using the first user's details, but I get a 400 if I try the other users.

I can make it work without using a for loop as such:

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
        if(req.body.username === database.users[0].username && 
           req.body.password === database.users[0].password) {
        res.json('successful signin');
    } else if (req.body.username === database.users[1].username && 
               req.body.password === database.users[1].password) {
        res.json('successful signin');
    } else if (req.body.username === database.users[2].username && 
               req.body.password === database.users[2].password) {
        res.json('successful signin');     
    } else {
        res.status(400).json('error logging in');
    }
})
```

I'm attempting to use a for loop just for cleaner code, knowing that I would use an actual database anyway in a real scenario. But I like a challenge! I'm just struggling with this one.

Any help would be immensely appreciated, thanks in advance!

Comment: Remember to mark which reply that answered your question by marking the checkbox beside the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try this code

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    for (var i=0; i < database.users.length; i++) {
            if (req.body.username === database.users[i].username && 
                req.body.password === database.users[i].password) {
            return res.json('successful signin');
        }
        
    }

    res.status(400).json('error logging in');
})
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! So it was pointless to have the response in the else statement? I can see it works but I'm not sure how different it is now - beside the response not being scoped within the for loop

Answer (score 1):

it's ok

first, define the login function

```
function login(user) {
    for (let i = 0; i < database.users.length; i++) {
        if (user.username === database.users[i].username &&
            user.password === database.users[i].password) {
            return true
        }
    }

}
```

Then

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    
    if(login(req.body)){
       return res.json('successful signin');
    }   

    res.status(400).json('error logging in');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First you don't need the forloop.

You can refactor that to this.

```js
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    const user = database.users.find((e) => 
       e.username === req.body.username && 
       e.password === req.body.password);
    if (user) res.json('successful signin');
    else res.status(400).json('error logging in');
})
```

Secondly The issue with your code is that it does not terminate after the user is authenticated.

Your code should be

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    for (var i=0; i < database.users.length; i++) {
        if (req.body.username === database.users[i].username && 
            req.body.password === database.users[i].password) {
            return res.json('successful signin');
        }
    }
    res.status(400).json('error logging in');
});
```

Final this is not a secure implementation for authentication. It is better you use a db like mongoose or sql. Also please ensure you password is hashed.

Comment: It's weird that you don't find anything wrong with the code. Check it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-minsky-m5ij1?file=/src/index.js) for yourself, what all is wrong.

Comment: Oh my bad no return statement

Answer (score 0):

#### Use Array.prototype.find()

Avoid loops and use [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method for better code readability. The method returns the entire user object if username and password match else undefined.

By adding `!!` the result would be a boolean value by which you can result the respective result from the API endpoint.

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
  // extract username and password from request body
  const { username: usr, password: pwd } = req.body;

  // check if user exists
  const userExists = !!database.users.find(({ username, password }) => username === usr && password === pwd);

  if (userExists) {
    return res.json('successful signin');
  }

  res.status(400).json('error logging in');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the way you structured your for-loop.

```
app.post('/signin', (req, res) => {
    for (var i=0; i < database.users.length; i++) {
            if (req.body.username === database.users[i].username && 
                req.body.password === database.users[i].password) {
            res.json('successful signin');
        } else {
        res.status(400).json('error logging in');
        }
    }
})
```

right now the computer will check, if the input in the req object matches with user i. And if it don't matches with user i, it will jump to your else statement and return a 400.

What you instead want to do is to let the for loop run through every possible user in the database, and only then if it didn't find any matches, it will jump to whatever you will write in after your else statement.